# F#: The '&' operator should not normally be redefined

Tags: f#, operators

When defining a custom operator from the limited set of single-character operators that can be both infix and prefix operators (`+ - % &`) I decided to use the ampersand, since it's the only one of those operators that I have not so far had occasion to use in my F# code. I reasoned that since & seems to have [fairly limited use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228(VS.100).aspx) in F#, redefining it would be least confusing to people using my library.

However, when I do so, I get a compiler warning:

> The '&' operator should not normally be redefined. Consider using a different operator name.

My question is, why does this seemingly-rare operator generate this warning message, while commonly-used operators like plus and minus do not? Also, how seriously should I take this warning?

Comment: Hmm, the only use of a single `&` sign that I know of is computing the address of a mutable value.

Comment: The linked page says that it's also "Used in AND patterns" but I haven't been able to find an example of what that means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When creating a custom operator, I generally prefer finding a simple combination of symbols that doesn't conflict with any existing F# operator. The true is that the symbol set is very limited, so this isn't always possible. However you can for example define something like `-&-` and you can often pick some combination that reflects the meaning of the operator. Just out of curiosity, what will the meaning your operator be?

Anyway, when I cannot find a good operator name, then I consider it as a sign that maybe I shouldn't use a custom operator (afterall, many languages live without them quite easily). I think the main use of custom operators is probably some specialized mathematical stuff. You can often replace operator (e.g. `a -&- b`) by a functiong used with pipelining (e.g. `a |> connectTo b`). There is also a [neat trick](http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/10516.aspx) that allows you to use functions as infix operators.

In case of `&`, I think it is a pretty reasonable option to ignore the warning if you have a good use for the operator and the behavior of the operator you want to define somehow corresponds with the intuition about the `&` symbol.

**EDIT** Defining your own `&` operator will not break the other use of the `&` symbol (in pattern matching). Here is an example of the *and pattern*:

```
// define custom & operator
let (&) a b = a + b

match 2 with
| num1 & num2 -> num1 + num2 // Still works fine
```

The *and pattern* allows you to match a single value agains multiple patterns in a single pattern (in the example above, we just bind it to two distinct values)

Comment: To answer your question about what I'm doing - I'm attempting to write a DSL for HTML generation, and I want to provide a convenient shortcut for something that's pretty common. The prefix version of the operator creates a Text node from a string, and the infix version wraps the Text node in a list, and passes it to the function that is the left-side argument. It's an occasion where I wish F# allowed implicit casting.

Comment: Link is dead now.

Answer (score 4):

You won't be able to call methods which take byref parameters.  This may or may not be a big deal for you.

As to your question about "AND patterns", here's a quick example.  However, note that defining your own unary `&` operator will not affect this behavior one way or the other.

```
let (|Contains|_|) (s:string) (x:string) =
  if (x.Contains(s)) then Some() else None

match "test" with
| Contains "e" & Contains "s" -> printfn "Success!"
| _ -> ()
```

Oddly, I only see the warning you mention when defining a **binary** `(&)` operator, not the unary `(~&)` operator.

**EDIT**

Although I don't see it called out explicitly in the spec, it looks like the binary `&` operator is used as a synonym for the binary `&&` operator.  I would guess that the suggestion not to redefine this operator exists because it is a short-circuiting operator, but your overload cannot be.

Comment: +1 - Great answer, and almost identical to Tomas's. I'm afraid I have to give him the nod for slightly more detail and the cool infix-function trick. Plus I like his book.